# Webpage resolution not changing on browser width change

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm designing a webpage and when I started working on its responsiveness, I noticed that the width of elements is way greater than the device width. It doesn't go beyond the screen but everything looks very small. 
Previously, when I've worked with webpages the width equaled the width of the device at max.
How can I fix this issue?

[image]

You see how the device width is 425px yet the header is 980px.

Comment: set overflow-x: auto to header. If you see a horizontal scrollbar then header have a width of 980px(or taking its prent's width). you can fix it either by giving relative width to elements or adding media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add meta tag for responsive site

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

if you have fixed width change that into percentage

then use media query for responsive design
if you are new to the responsive design there are many tutorials available online to begin you can use w3schools.com site

Comment: wow! yes that's it! I didn't even know we had to do that. Thank You!